# My objects in my array are going to null (java)

Tags: java, file, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I have this while loop that is pulling information from a file and making new objects and then placing the objects into an array and for some reason the while loop iterates once for each if statement and then exits so all the other lines are made null. Here is my while loop

````
// open file and create array
        File file = new File("Adventures.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(file);
        Adventure[] array = new Adventure[myReader.nextInt()];
        int i = 0;
        // reading file
        while (myReader.hasNext()) {
            if ("Zipline".equals(myReader.next())) {
                array[i] = new Zipline(myReader.nextDouble(), myReader.nextDouble());
                i++;
            }
            if ("Snorkel".equals(myReader.next())) {
                array[i] = new Snorkel(myReader.nextDouble(), myReader.nextDouble());
                i++;
            }
            if ("Helicopter".equals(myReader.next())) {
                array[i] = new Helicopter(myReader.nextDouble(), myReader.nextDouble());
                i++;
            }
        } // while loop
    ```
````

Comment: So it could be that the scanner is not reading in the data that you think. Try putting a breakpoint after the read and checking that you have the correct string ("Snorkel") etc coming in

Comment: This might not be the whole fix for your issue, but one thing you should take care of. You are reading new content for every `if` clause. For every loop iteration, you should read the content once (e.g. `String temp = myReader.next()`) and then compare the content (`"Zipline".equals(temp)`). Wouldn't also hurt then to change the 2nd and 3rd `if`s to `else if`.

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] your question and post [part of] the file `Adventures.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of the loop is using too many values, because each call to `myReader.next()` is consuming another token. Store the token in a variable, so you can check it multiple times.

```java
while (myReader.hasNext()) {
    String token = myReader.next();
    if ("Zipline".equals(token)) {
        array[i++] = new Zipline(myReader.nextDouble(), myReader.nextDouble());
    }
    if ("Snorkel".equals(token)) {
        array[i++] = new Snorkel(myReader.nextDouble(), myReader.nextDouble());
    }
    if ("Helicopter".equals(token)) {
        array[i++] = new Helicopter(myReader.nextDouble(), myReader.nextDouble());
    }
} // while loop
```

Or use a `switch` statement:

```java
while (myReader.hasNext()) {
    switch (myReader.next()) {
        case "Zipline":
            array[i++] = new Zipline(myReader.nextDouble(), myReader.nextDouble());
            break;
        case "Snorkel":
            array[i++] = new Snorkel(myReader.nextDouble(), myReader.nextDouble());
            break;
        case "Helicopter":
            array[i++] = new Helicopter(myReader.nextDouble(), myReader.nextDouble());
            break;
    }
} // while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to implement BuffeRedreader, that might look something like this :

```
objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\Adventures.txt"));
```

The difference between Scanner and BuffeRedreader is that buffers read faster and are more accurate giving results.
Personally I changed to Buffer because Errors from Scanner didn't apply to buffer.
I hope I could help